# Match line breaks in lines that are not starting with a special character

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to match all `\n` or `\r` except the ones when the line starts with a `@`
I have this regular expression :
 `(?!^@.*\r*\n*)(\r*\n*)`
For example:

```
@text text text 

@text text text
The line break after this text should be matched 
The line break after this text also should be selected 

@this line break should not be selected
```

So the only line breaks that should be selected are the ones in the 2nd, 4th, 5th,and 6th and 7th.
 Any ideas?

Comment: "\n\r" is a non-standard linebreak, also in addition to these, your text is in multiple lines. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I just added the \n and \r to make it clear in the example, Yeah my text is in multiple lines, I thought I can just add the m flag, right? If it works for one line

Comment: You do realize, that e.g. "\n" is a newline, and that "\r" is also somewhat a line delimiter?

Comment: What platform does use `\n\r` as linebreak? AFAIK Linux/Unix uses `\n`, Mac uses `\r`, windows uses `\r\n`

Comment: As described, "\n\r" is non-standard. "\r" was only used on old macs (i don't think they do nowadays?). However, due to that legacy reason, e.g. the multiline flag `m` still sees "\r" as a line delimiter. This causes very annoying behavior, when using it on a string, that has CRLF line endings.

Comment: Anyways, imho your question is unclear. You want to "match `\n` or `\r`", which are line endings, except the ones when "the line" starts with a "@". Which line? Before or after, "\n", "\r", "\r\n", or your non-standard "\n\r"? Also note, that one "line" in your question text ends with only "\n" instead of "\r\n". Is that intentional, or a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

https://regex101.com/r/bYIpiQ/2

https://regexr.com/4s98n

Note I do not SELECT the text, I REPLACE the \n\r or\n or \r

```js
const text = document.getElementById("x").innerText;
document.getElementById("x").innerText=text.replace(/(^[^@].*)(\r\n|\r|\n)/gm,"$1<BR/>")
```

```css
#x { font-family: "Courier New", monospace;
  white-space: pre; }
```

```html
<div id="x">@line 1: text text text 
line 2:
@line3: text text text
line 4: The line break after this text should be matched 
line 5: The line break after this text also should be selected 
line 6:
@line 7: this line break should not be selected
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it did not work , I do not get the same matches as you, I get all the text that has a line break and does not start with a @

Comment: I have edited my question, so it is clear now I hope. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I test with https://regexr.com/ but i get different results..

Comment: It matches all the text, I just want to match the line breaks, because I want to replace them with another string..

Comment: My code only CHANGES the selected \r\n and leaves the text alone

Comment: Do you want to select \r\nText where Text does not start with @ or do you want to select Text\n\r where text does not start with @

Comment: I only need to only get the line breaks after any line that doesnt start with @, not the text it self , just the line breaks

Comment: So I get them in my replace. What do you want to do with them

Comment: Yes, No doubt, your code is working, but when i past your reges in https://regexr.com/ I get different matches. I know that you are replacing the matched values $1, with XX .

Comment: I have edited the example, I removed the \n and \r from the text, because I just wanted to make sure the example is clear, but maybe you misunderstood me. Can you try with this text now? the match should be only the linebreaks,

Comment: Ok, this is weird, because I get the `line 2:` as the first match, normally I want only the line break matched, because I want to remove it (replace it with an empty string)

Comment: You may want to add a + to the (\r\n|\r|\n): `(\r\n|\r|\n)+` if there are empty lines

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this. Use split to split the string with line break ‘\n’, this will replace all the line breaks in the string and return the array of string. Now loop through the array and check if the line starts with 
‘@‘ then append line break at the end of the line .

With this approach you can add line break where ever you want.

```js
let values = `@text text text 

@text text text
The line break after this text should be matched 
The line break after this text also should be selected 

@this line break should not be selected`;

values = values.split(/\n/); // split all with line break

values.forEach((value, index) => {
  if (value.match(/^@.*/gm)) {
    values[index] = value + " <br>"; // or add \n
  } 
});
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = values.join('');
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```